# Node - connect-flash not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, web, frontend

I'm trying to display an error message with connect-flash but it seems not working. I've tried several ways to do this work but any of that worked. I gotta an web app with a similar config code and worked without any problem.

here is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const moment = require('moment')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const db = require('./configs/db')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', 'views')
app.set(db)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
app.use(flash());
var sessionFlash = function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    next();

}
app.use(sessionFlash)




app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  req.flash('error', 'Welcome');
  res.render('test', {
    title: 'Home',
  })
});
app.get('/addFlash', function (req, res) {
  req.flash('error', 'Flash Message Added');
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

my EJS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%  if(error){ %>
      <div class="">
          <h1><%=error%></h1>
      </div>
    <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that you're not serving your server over HTTPS, in which case the following will prevent session cookies from being set:

```
cookie: { secure: true }
```

See [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookiesecure).